# What CSS should I use to get a border around an option tag in both Firefox and IE?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Right now I am using the following CSS:

```
option
{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Which works fine in Firefox but not in IE.  I'm not sure if it makes a difference but the option tags are generated by an ASP.NET ListBox control.

Comment: Whatever the asp.net control generates, once generated it is plain old CSS and HTML. You can prove this to yourself by capturing the page source in Firefox, saving it as a plain html file, and serving that to both Firefox and IE. I'm therefore removing the asp.net tag.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  My concern was that asp.net might be adding some of it's own CSS that was overriding my CSS, which is why I added the tag.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the styling of `option` elements is supported to different degrees by different browsers.  Firefox is the only browser which allows you to add a border around `option`s – IE and Chrome won't show a border.

[Here's an overview of what styles different browsers support.](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single-option/)  The only styling you can reliably apply is background and foreground color.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way it would work?!

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Never had problems with this, could be something else , parent elements and so on...

Comment: Hmm, didn't work.  I'm begining to suspect that the asp.net ListBox might be doing something weird?

Comment: Then check your code in Firebug first, usually you'd see something overriding your CSS, after that you can try isolation of that little piece of HTML, and last turn on IE's debugger, last because to me and my colleagues usually crashes IE and/or entire OS.

Comment: Ok i looked at it in firebug and Develop Tools.  In developer tools it doesnt look like the style is even being found for the option tag.  Firebug finds the correct styles.  When I look at the source for the page the CSS is in there though.  I also noticed a `border-collapse: collapse` style is being applied, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Add a border-color to your declaration.

```
option
{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: No dice, do you think it could have something to do with the asp.net ListBox?

Comment: @Abe, It doesn't The ASP ListBox renders out to standard HTML. So you are dealing with the rendering of that HTML in each browser