# Border bottom for select box option not working on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select

I would like to `underline` the disabled options on a `select` box. See my code,

**CODE**

```css
#myselect option {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #1A1F24;
}
#myselect option:disabled {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ABB6C0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ABB6C0;
}
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

This code works fine in firefox. Not working in chrome. How to make work this in chrome too ?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/cqm8anc2/)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-optgroup-option-css-chrome/) from ElectricToolbox , `border` it isn't a property that you can style in `select`/`option`/`optgroup` when using Chrome.

Here is the properties you can style:

- **`font-style`**
- **`font-weight`**
- **`color`**
- **`background-color`**
- **`font-family`**
- **`font-size`**
- **`padding`**

**Note** : that some of these properties above only work for one the elements, for example, `padding` only will work in `select`

If you want to customize `selects` you may want to try some of the selects plugins out here, like :

- [Bootstrap Select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)
- [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Comment: I believe `border` works fine for `<select>`, just not `<option>` or `<optgroup>`. I only mention this because `<select>` was singled out at the beginning of your answer for the `border` property.

Comment: ^ I am only here from Google because `border` is *not* working in Chrome for my `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can only use borders for `option` elements in Firefox as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452681/what-css-should-i-use-to-get-a-border-around-an-option-tag-in-both-firefox-and-i).

You would need to create a custom drop down list control to achieve a universal solution. Check out [Custom Drop-Down List Styling](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) for some examples.