# Dropdown with border

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get a dropdown in particular style but I am not able to achieve it. This is what i want

[image]

I tried using `<select>` and Material UI's `SelectField` and applied border type to it's stype but that didn't work either. How can I get this border to work?

Comment: You just use `select {}` for styling select boxes. If you want it to be more specific, you'll need to provide your code.

Comment: see the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221983/border-bottom-for-select-box-option-not-working-on-chrome) on border issues with selects, and then see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) for lots more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried styling the select

```css
select.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<select class="dropdown">
  <option selected value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very common yet you not created any div for the element
select.

There are two ways you can do

1. Add div to your element:-

```html
<html>
<head> 
<style>
select.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<body>
<div>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option selected value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2) You can also use outline propety (no need of div) :-

```html
<html>
<head> 
<style>
select.dropdown {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<body>

<select class="dropdown">
  <option selected value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I guess that should help you.